# display data of slected date in react js

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to show names and times of selected dates  `datetaker` has a selected date iwant to pass it to the reducer and get name and time of the selected date and display it

```
var datetaker = props.selectedDate;
```

```
const data = [
 { id: 1, date: "2021-10-04", time: "18:00" ,name:"ram" },
 { id:3, date: "2021-10-06", time: "19:00",name:"hari" },
 { id: 2, date: "2021-10-07", time: "19:00",name:"ski"  },
 { id: 5, date: "2021-10-08", time: "19:00",name:"rai"  },
];
let mapped = data.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.date] = [...(r[a.date] || []), a];
  return r;
}, {});


Object.values(mapped).map((item, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <h1>
    todays date {item[0].date}
    </h1>
    <div>
      {item.map((e) => {
        return <p key={e.time}>{e.time} {e.name}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

**note**: there can be multiple entry in same date

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
export default function App() {
  var datetaker = ["2021-10-04", "2021-10-04"]
  const data = [
    { id: 1, date: "2021-10-04", time: "18:00" ,name:"ram" },
    { id:3, date: "2021-10-04", time: "19:00",name:"hari" },
    { id: 2, date: "2021-10-07", time: "19:00",name:"ski"  },
    { id: 5, date: "2021-10-08", time: "19:00",name:"rai"  },
   ];

   const filteredDate = data.filter(el => datetaker.includes(el.date))
   
   return filteredDate.map((item, index) => (
     <div key={index}>
       <h1>
       todays date {item.date}
       </h1>
       <div>
          <p>{item.time} {item.name}</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   ))
}
```